# You don't have write permissions for the /var/lib/gems/2.3.0 directory

Tags: ruby, bundler

```
gem install bundler
```

После этой вот команды

Comment: Ну, вот же у вас ответ прямо в самом вопросе: что нет прав на запись в директорию. Нужно выставить права на запись для этой директории.

Comment: И как это делаеться? Будьте так любезны пояснить!)

Comment: К примеру: `chmod -R 766 /var/lib/gems/2.3.0`. Подробней можете почитать здесь про выдачу прав: http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0_unix

Comment: @ragmon **Нет, не надо так делать!** Это открывает шикарный способ повышения привилегий путём передачи на исполнение произвольного кода через подмену гемов.

Comment: А как надо делать?

Comment: @CTapbINneHb Если у Вас возник новый вопрос, задайте его при помощи кнопки «[Задать вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)». Если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, а где ты увидел новый вопрос?

Answer (score 8):

**Вы попытались установить гем в системный репозиторий, не имея на то привилегий.**

В первую очередь, **разрешения установлены не без причины**. Обычно общесистемный репозиторий гемов считается безопасным для *всех* пользователей системы, включая привилегированных. Поэтому то, что к его изменению доступ ограничен, резонно. Иначе кто угодно мог бы добавить туда код, которым мог вы воспользоваться (не зная об изменениях) пользователь с высокими полномочиями.

Так что разрешения к той папке не трогайте. Есть другие варианты.

---

## `--user-install`

Гемы можно установить в собственную папку пользователя ("домашний репозиторий"), если они потребуются только ему. За это отвечает флаг `--user-install`.

```
gem install --user-install bundler
```

Чтобы не указывать этот флаг каждый раз и по умолчанию всё держать "дома": нужно в домашней папке сделать файл `.gemrc` (скорее всего, у вас его не существует) и убедиться, что у опции `install` есть флаг `--user-install`. Файл **только** с этой опцией может выглядеть так:

```yaml
---
install: --user-install
```

Можно добавить этот и другие флаги аналогичным образом и для других подкоманд `gem`, не только `install`.

---

## `sudo`

Если устанавливаемые гемы нужны всем, можно поставить их и с `sudo` в "системный репозиторий". Пользоваться гемами в этом репозитории смогут все. Но что попало туда устанавливать не стоит, по причине, описанной в начале ответа.

---

## Менеджеры версий

На машине разработчика обычно имеет смысл держать несколько версий Ruby, для чего обычно используют менеджер версий. [RVM](http://rvm.io/) мне видится самым простым в использовании, но есть также [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) и обобщённый на много языков [asdf](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf).

У них у всех есть документация, и при обычной установке они всё своё "имущество" держат с домашней папке пользователя, посему не требуют прав суперпользователя для работы.

Comment: Ноут мой. Я единственный пользователь. И указан как админ. Так что не вижу великого смысла ставить для "отдельного" пользователя. Через sudo не хотел вставать без изменения прав. Спасиб за Ваш ответ.

Comment: @CTapbINneHb судя по тому, что в доступе вам отказали, вы **не** админ, но указаны в `sudoers`, что позволяет вам иногда брать права админа с явным подтверждением. И пользователей у вас на машине, скорее всего, целый ворох (у меня их 39, список выводит `cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd`). И канитель с `sudo` нужна затем, чтобы вы могли относительно спокойно выполнять любые действия без опасений разнести/заразить всю систему самостоятельно или чьей-нибудь ловкой копипастой.

Comment: Три дефиса в содержимом файла `.gemrc` - это опечатка или так и должно быть?

Comment: @Qwertiy так и задумано.

Comment: @D-side, а что означают? А то я руби не видел даже, но выглядит странным :)

Comment: @Qwertiy а это YAML.